# c++ How to check string parsing order

Tags: c++11

I am a beginner in c++. I have multi line input from command line like below.

```
A {1,2,3,4}
B {2,1,4,9}
c {5,8,7,6}
```

My aim is to read each line and to do some action based on the first letter in line. I have a code like below.

```
while(getline(cin,input)){
stringstream ss(input);
string letter;

while(!ss.eof()){
ss >> letter;
if (letter == "A")
{
    Do this
}
if (letter == "B")
{
    Do this
}
if (letter== "C")
{
    Do this
}
}
}
```

Now I want to ensure that after A, only B has to be given as input and not A again or C. After B and C input can be in any order. Is there any easy way to check the order of input?

Comment: Keep track of the letters you've already parsed and then check if the preceding letter has been parsed before you `Do this`. There is no magic helper to do it with.

Comment: `Is there any easy way to check the order of input?` Yes.  Parse `argv[]` to see what's there.  Also, for the first letter in the line, just peek at `std::string[0]` to determine what is there.